# jquery:how to get the id of anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I have 2 anchor tags

```
<li><a id="tab1" href="#tabs-1">Issue</a></li>
<li><a id="tab2" href="#tabs-2">Change Request</a></li>
```

I have the following jquery:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
                                alert($('a').attr("id"));
            });
```

What happens:
I always get "tab1" in the pop up

What I need:
when user clicks on an anchor tag, its id needs to be displayed in the pop up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem lies in the alert statement: with `$('a')`, you aren't referencing the clicked `<a>` element in the alert statement—you're retrieving the first `<a>` element in the document.

Instead, to reference the clicked element, replace `$('a')` with `$(this)`:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply

I get an error like


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 57
Char: 17
Code: 0

If i replace this.attr("id") with this the error goes off but the popup shows the full url 
http://sever/folder/#tab1

Comment: @balalakshmi: OK, it seems jQuery likes `$(this)` rather than the plain JavaScript `this`. Does it work if you use `$(this)` instead (see my updated code snippet)?

Comment: +1 for the spending the time to explain why the original code does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    var currentElemID = $(this).attr("id") // or you can use this.id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get any element attribute using attr() so:

```
$('a').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to access the id, then using jQuery is an unnecessary overhead:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```